# Interchange of Limit and Integration

Tags: measure-theory

(1) Let $f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative function. 
 We will say that $f$ is (Jordan) integrable if the region bounded by $f$, $x$-axis, and the lines $x=0$ and $x=1$ is [Jordan measurable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure), and in this case we define $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ to be the Jordan measure of the region mentioned above.

(2) We can find a sequence of functions $f_n\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  such that each $f_n$ is (Jordan) integrable, $f_n$ converges to $f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, limit of $\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx$ exists, but 
$f$ is not (Jordan) integrable, and hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\neq \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ . (See [Stein-Shakarchi](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=2Sg3Vug65AsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=stein%20shakarchi%20real%20analysis&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z5EKVIWbOoaVuASTvoCYCg&ved=0CB8QuwUwAA#v=onepage&q=stein%20shakarchi%20real%20analysis&f=false) - Real Analysis, p.40, Exercise 10).

(3) Suppose now instead of Jordan measure, we consider [outer measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) (i.e. Lebesgue exterior measure). Since outer measure is defined for every subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we define the $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ to be the outer measure of the graph of $f$ and interval $[0,1]$ on $x$-axis. My question is

**Question** *Is there a sequence of functions $f_n\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n$ converges (pointwise) to a function $f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\neq \int_0^1 f(x)dx$?*

(In the question, the integrals are understood as outer measures of regions under grapf of functions).

Comment: Can you draw a sequence of nonnegative continuous functions $f_n$ with the following properties? (1) $f_n$ is zero on $[0,(n-1)/n] \cup \{1\}$. (2) each $f_n$ has an integral of 1.

Comment: Interesting! Can we obtain a sequence $\{f_n\}$ which is non-negative as well as monotonically increasing (i.e. $0\leq f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$), which satisfies conditions in the question? In other words, does the monotone convergence theorem holds with understanding of integration as outer measure of region under the function?

Comment: I'm not sure. It would be enough to find an increasing sequence of subsets $A_n \subseteq [0,1]$ such that the outer measure of the union wasn't the limit of the outer measures of the sets $A_n$. Then you'd take the indicator functions.